# Legacy auth continuation in UWP

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-mobile-services

I have a Windows 8/RT app that I wrote a few years back in which I used Azure Mobile Services and the Live SDK to authenticate the User via the User's Microsoft account.

Now I'm rewriting the UI from scratch as a UWP app and I'm seriously struggling to figure out how to implement authentication, now, in a way that when a User saves data in 1 version of the app, I can show it to them in the other version.
It seems that MS is pushing us to Azure AD, but I can find little to help me and all of the examples I can find are either not supported on UWP or no longer supported by Azure.

Can I please get some direction....where to find examples of currently supported code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was far more difficult than it should've been and that, I think, has everything to do with how fast things are changing and the difficulty of keeping the documentation up-to-date while battling against the search engines that are prone to providing the most viewed information which, in this case, is out-of-date and obsolete and no longer works.

As far as Bruce's answer, I tried.  First of all, it seems that my Mobile Apps have automatically been migrated to App Services in Azure.  Secondly, the Microsoft Graph implementation will authenticate but creates a disconnect as the information returned by the authentication process doesn't match the information returned from the Live SDK which I use for uniquely identifying the User.  Therefore, using the Graph implementation disconnects my Users from all of the data they have asked me to store for them.  Thirdly, the articles linked in the 2nd paragraph (despite being written 6 months ago) are out-of-date, use obsolete tools such as the "Classic" Azure Portal and assume your creating a new app thus allowing a template to do a great deal of the configuration and such that I needed.

I do sincerely appreciate the effort, though, Bruce.

Last year I implemented auth in a UWP app using the OneDrive SDK.  I encountered 2 problems with trying to do that in the new app:

1. The version I used last year was a full version old (1.15 v 2.0.6)...as are the great majority of tutorials about how to use the SDK that I could find on the internet.  Everything seems to be about the OneDriveClientExtensions class...which no longer exists.  But I didn't particularly want to be stuck with the version from 2015 and never be able to upgrade.  Since the newest version is already 6 months old, I'm kinda scared anyway.
2. The newest version requires, for auth purposes, that you also install the Microsoft.OneDriveSDK.Authentication package.  This was last updated 5 months ago, but is dependent on v2 of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory which is at version 3.13 (although it appears v2 is still being worked on).  Where this becomes a real pain is that the UWP Community Toolkit Services library requires v3 of that same package so you can't have both the Toolkit Services AND OneDriveSDK Authentication packages installed in the same project.  Fortunately, since I couldn't get the UWP Services library to do what I wanted it to do, I didn't really need it.

So, I removed the UWP Services package from my solution and installed the latest OneDrive SDK packages and rummaged around the internet looking for examples of how to use that version and I finally found this:

```
var scopes = new string[] { "wl.signin" };
var client = new OnlineIdAuthenticationProvider(scopes);
await client.AuthenticateUserAsync();
```

Then you can access the client's CurrentAccountSession property to get the UserId.

Now, I'm sure this is a temporary solution as, eventually, the OneDrive SDK will be obsolete and I'll need to use some library that's dependent on v3 of the ActiveDirectory package, but until then, this works.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I have checked the [Live SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LiveSDK/5.6.2/) and found that the latest version is v5.6.3 and the last updated at Wednesday, July 8, 2015. Also, I have checked this lib could not work in my UWP app (target version: Windows 10.0;Build 10240).

I assumed that you could invoke Microsoft Graph via the Azure AD v2.0 endpoint with Microsoft account for authentication. For more details, you could refer to [Get started with Microsoft Graph in a universal Windows 10 app](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/get-started/uwp) and this [git sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/uwp-csharp-connect-rest-sample).

Or you could [migrate your azure mobile service to azure app service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-migrating-from-mobile-services) and configure the server-side [Microsoft Account authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-microsoft-authentication), then refer to this official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-users) about adding authentication to your Windows app.